# Finding keys with the minimum values in each group in a dictionary with jumps (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary where jumps happen in its keys. How can I find the key in between each group where the value is minimum?
For example, I have

```py
myDict = {
        0.98:0.001,
        1.0:0.002,
        1.02: 0.0001,
        3.52:0.01,
        3.57:0.004,
        3.98: 0.005,
        4.01: 0.02,
        6.87: 0.01,
        6.90:0.02,
        6.98:0.001,
        7.0: 0.02
}
```

My desired output would be `1.02, 3.57, 6.98`.
The actual dictionary I'm working with has over 1000 items.

Comment: What do you mean by _jumps_? And, is your question, which key has the minimum value? Could you please explain why `3.57` is desired output?

Comment: How close together do they need to be to be considered a cluster?

Comment: @LoukasPap by jumps i mean in the, for example first 3 keys the maximum difference is 1.02-0.98=0.04 but this difference suddenly gets bigger as we look at the fourth key. 3.52-1.02=2.50. If we consider keys between each jump a "group", I want the keys that have the minimum value within each group. For example among the first three keys, I want 1.02 (since its value is 0.0001 and smaller than 0.001 and 0.002), from the next four keys I want 3.57 (with the value 0.004) and so on.

Comment: @user2390182 Their difference would have to be less than 1.

Comment: So, in the group `1.02-0.98=0.04`, is the 2nd key (1.0) included because it is between the 1st and 3rd key, or is it left alone (and it may goes to another group)?

Comment: @LoukasPap I don't think I understand your question. Between each group I need the key with the minimum value. The rest of the items of the group (keys and value) would be discarded.

Comment: I don't understand what makes a group. We see that: `1.0-0.98=0.2`, so why do we look at the 3rd key that makes the difference bigger (`1.2-0.98=0.4`)? Shouldn't we just keep the group of 1st and 2nd key, and keep `0.98` which has the lowest value (`0.001`)?

Comment: @LoukasPap the numbers close to each other make a group. The first three are closer to each other compared to the other keys. Let me put it this way. If the difference between a number of keys is less than 1, they'd form a group (or a cluster as they are apparently called ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, supposing the dictionary is sorted in ascending order according to key (explanations in the comments of the code):

```py
def main():
    d = {
        0.98: 0.001, 1.0: 0.002, 1.02: 0.0001,
        3.52: 0.01, 3.57: 0.004, 3.98: 0.005, 4.01: 0.02,
        6.87: 0.01, 6.90: 0.02, 6.98: 0.001, 7.0: 0.02
    }

    all_groups = []  # list to store the groups
    minimums = []  # list to store all mins
    # initializing holders for minimum key and value
    min_k = 1000
    min_v = 0

    for k, v in d.items():
        # an if-statement just to add the first group with key inside
        if len(all_groups) == 0:
            all_groups.append([k])
            min_k = k
            min_v = d.get(k)
        else:
            # check if the difference is less or equal to 1
            if k - all_groups[-1][-1] <= 1.0:
                all_groups[-1].append(k)

                # each time we add a key to a group, we check if it is the minimum
                if d.get(k) < min_v:
                    min_k = k
                    min_v = d.get(k)
            else:
                minimums.append((min_k, min_v))

                # we append a new list with the new key inside to `all_groups`
                # in which we will store the next elements
                all_groups.append([k])
                min_k = k
                min_v = d.get(k)

    minimums.append((min_k, min_v))  # adding last minimums because for loop ends without adding them

    for i in minimums:
        print(i[0])  # 1.02, 3.57, 6.98


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use itertools.accumulate to generate group numbers where each "jump" would increase the group number by 1.  Then get the first entry in each group using itertools.groupby:

```
from itertools import accumulate,groupby

group  = accumulate(k-prev>1 for k,prev in zip(myDict,(min(myDict),*myDict)))
result = [k for _,(k,*_) in groupby(myDict,lambda _:next(group))]

print(result)
[0.98, 3.52, 6.87]
```